# Complex transformation on one column, while keeping original columns in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like specific separations of values within my column to display the  first word and the number along with its 'T' value. I would like the first 'word' that is separated by '-' and its #T value.

**Data**

```
type                                        total   free   use

AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A        10      5      5
AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A        10      4      6
AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A        10      1      9
AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A    10      8      2
AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A    10      3      7
```

**Desired**

```
type            total   free   use

AY12 12T        10      5      5
AY12 12T        10      4      6
AY12 12T        10      1      9
AY12 6.4T       10      8      2
AY12 6.4T       10      3      7
```

**Doing**

```
import pandas as pd

def extract_value(s):
    regex = re.search(r'(^.+?)-.+?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?T)', s)
    if regex:
        first_word = regex.group(1)
        code = regex.group(2)
        return f'{first_word} {code}'
    return s

df.columns = ['type', 'total', 'free', 'use']
```

However, the transformation is not occurring and this is the result:

```
type                                        total   free   use

AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A        10      5      5
AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A        10      4      6
AY12-AYY-AY-R800-900G-12T_18T-R6-v.A        10      1      9
AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A    10      8      2
AY12-AYY-AY-R800XD-900G-6.4T-R11-WOW-v.A    10      3      7
```

I am still researching. Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: How are you passing values of type column to the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
df['type']=df['type'].str.extract('(\w+(?=[-AYY]))')+ " "+ df['type'].str.extract('(?<=0G-)(.*?)(?=\-|_)')



     type  total  free  use
0   AY12 12T     10     5    5
1   AY12 12T     10     4    6
2   AY12 12T     10     1    9
3  AY12 6.4T     10     8    2
4  AY12 6.4T     10     3    7
```

Comment: let me try. Thank you @wwnde

Comment: Hi this Is just a sample set, my large dataset has first words that do not start with AY - would this still work? (It works on the sample) thanks

Comment: Extract the alphanumeric at the start of string `df['type']=df['type'].str.extract('(^\w+)')+ " "+ df['type'].str.extract('(?<=0G-)(.*?)(?=\-|_)')
print(df)
`

Comment: oh actually this is not working - the type field shows NANs

Comment: It should work. Unless you provide a more diverse and representative sample data set I have no way to tell where you are running into issues because my answer works with the sample data availed.  Feel free to accept and use the other answer given for this question

Comment: Your solution works for the sample. I have just posted a new question which has sample set that is closer to my dataset. Please could you look at this

Answer (score 1):

While I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, this should work

```
df['type'] = df['type'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall(r'(^.+?)-.+?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?T)', x)[0]))
```

Comment: let me try. Thank you